# How to delete rows with conditions postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

**I have a postgres table with multiple rows that have one item in common. How can I remove a row if it was true or none on the table**

| id | email | verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jason@gmail.com | true |
| 2 | jason@gmail.com | none |
| 3 | benita@outlook.com | none |
| 4 | benita@outlook.com | none |

**Expected Result:**

| id | email | verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jason@gmail.com | true |
| 3 | benita@outlook.com | none |

Answer (score 0):

You use a window function to select the rows you want to keeo

The `ORDER BY` chooses `true` over `none`, so that veried emails are choosen as row number 1 if both exist., the second sorting column is `id` which will get the lowest id, if two or more equal emails exist.

But you should redesign your table and mal email unique, so that multiple identical emails can't be inserted

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     ("id" int, "email" varchar(18), "verified" varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     ("id", "email", "verified")
> VALUES
>     (1, 'jason@gmail.com', 'true'),
>     (2, 'jason@gmail.com', 'none'),
>     (3, 'benita@outlook.com', 'none'),
>     (4, 'benita@outlook.com', 'none')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM tab1
> WHERE "id" IN 
> (SELECT "id"
> FROM (SELECT "id"
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "email" ORDER BY "verified" DESC, "id") rn FROM tab1) t1
> WHERE rn > 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECt * FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | email              | verified
> -: | :----------------- | :-------
>  1 | jason@gmail.com    | true    
>  3 | benita@outlook.com | none
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=588c0aeeb95fee7a8829c14529bae04a)*

Comment: Could you explain what happens here: 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "email" ORDER BY "verified" DESC, "id") rn FROM tab1) t1
WHERE rn > 1)

Comment: the line add a row number to all rows, Partition marks, how the window function groups values together, so that all have their number, every group has their own number starting with 1, The order by is already explainrd, do in short first we sort every group(email) so tht true comes first, that it becomes number 1, as second sortingcolumn is the id, as you wanted the lowest id,  if there are multiple identocal memails with the same verified status